# Extra Grub entry: Windows 7

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, xubuntu

My Toshiba laptop came with Windows 7 pre-installed. I installed Xubuntu on dual-boot (BIOS not UEFI). When Windows 10 came out, I upgraded to it, but now Grub shows two entries for Windows (besides the Windows Recovery Environment):

```
Windows 10 (on /dev/sda1)
Windows 7 (on /dev/sda2)
```

Windows 10 is installed on /dev/sda2 and there's no Windows 7 anymore.

I'm suspecting that the Windows bootloader is on sda1, but why is there a Windows 7 (which doesn't boot) and how do I remove the entry from Grub?

Is there any modification I can do to the `/etc/grub.d/30_os-prober` file to avoid this Windows 7 entry from being added when grub is updated?

Comment: Grub2's os-prober looks for Windows boot files. If sda1 has bootmgr & BCD then grub assumes it is bootable. But newer Windows often reuses old boot partition, so make sure sda1 is not the boot partition for Windows on sda2. The primary NTFS partition with boot flag & boot files is the real boot partition for all Windows. Other partitions with boot files may or may not be required. Post this: '`sudo parted -l`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a tool called Grub Costomizer (from https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer). You can reorder, add and delete grub items. You would need the deleting functionallity. Although your windows 7 will maybe be readded when you update grub, it is easy to redelete it. (i can do it within 5 minutes)

Comment: This extra entry didn't bother me when I was using this laptop regularly, but now it is being used by others who are not tech savvy and I would like to reduce the "confusion" in  the Grub menu by leaving the useful entries only.

Comment: You can do that with grub customizer too

Comment: I would rather avoid having to edit the grub menu every time there is a new kernel.

Comment: I dont think this will happen. It is possible some glitches can occur, but I only have good experiences with it

Comment: Tried removing the windows 7 entry with Grub customizer and then run `sudo update-grub` and the entry was not added again.

Comment: Nice. Thanks for the rep points btw